# Passing Managed Object Data Through didSelectRow UIPickerView

Tags: core-data, uipickerview, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm a bit lost on how to pass my fetched managed object data through a didSelectRow UIPickerView action.

On the previous view, I passed the CalcInfo object like this:

```
CalcInfo *calc = (CalcInfo *)[_calcInfos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
self.myPageOneViewController.calcInfos = calc;
```

I was successfully able to use calcInfos.attribute for all my IBAction:(id)sender buttons, but the pickerView isn't able to fetch / use the data. The updateLabel action always has calcInfos.attribute as NULL. Here's a bit of my code

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
[self updateLabel];
```

}

```
- (void)updateLabel {

double stdrate = [calcInfos.infusionstd doubleValue];
double lowrate = [calcInfos.infusionlow doubleValue];

if (calcInfos.infusionlow == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"It's null");
}
```

}

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I found my solution! I had this gut feeling there was something wrong with my data references in the xib file. Initially, I had the delegate and dataSource reference my PageOneViewController, but I tried referencing File's Owner, and it works! It was really weird that all my buttons worked with retrieving my calcInfos variable, but the pickerView wasn't able to...

Answer (score 0):

The picker view is a subview with its own hardwired controller. It returns the row and column/component picked in its delegate message `didSelectRow:inComponent'.

You need to pass that info along to your `updateLabel` method so that you can relate the pickerview selection to your managed objects. Right now, the method does nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think you've directed me to the right place. However, I'm not sure how to pass the calcInfos object to my updateLabel method.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying that the pickerView is in it's own subview, so the didSelectRow:inComponent message and hence the updateLabel method doesn't connect with the main view? That's why I'm not able to call my managed object attributes from the subview? My updateLabel method can call the attributes when I call the method from a UIButton IBAction. It's odd to me that I'd have to send my managed object information into the pickerView subview to have the updateLabel method "see" it.

Comment: The pickerview doesn't share any data with the controller. It just returns to its delegate (which might or might not be the controller.) So, if you want to provide data from the pickerview, you must do so explicitly. Your `updateLabel` method does not know what the pickerview selection was unless you pass the values to it explicitly.